# Invisible mythical unexpected token on unexisting line in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

So today, node don't run my app, because it finds unexpected token at line 219.
Here is the full error log:

```
syberic@syberic:~/Web/lotalot$ node app.js
/home/syberic/Web/lotalot/config/passport.js:219
});
 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/syberic/Web/lotalot/app.js:22:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:141:18)
    at node.js:933:3
```

BUT the **PROBLEM** is, the file `passport.js` Has **217** lines!
Here is a screenshot of how the end of this file looks in VIM:
[image]
I inspected the file with some other text editors, mousepad, gedit, etc. But the file always have 217 lines. When i add some empty lines to the end of the file, unexpected token moves down respectively. What kind of **MAGIC** is this? How can this happen? I'm so damn frustrated.

Comment: Are you transpiling your code with Babel or something? If you are and sourcemaps are turned off, that would explain the differing line numbers.

Comment: How to undestand if code is transpiling? I think i don't, it's just pure express app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this means you have an extra opening brace in your program.  Internally, Node pastes the text of your program inside a function, so there are some extra characters before your file contents and an extra line after it.  I can reproduce this easily with this one-line file that has just an open brace in it:

```
$ cat foo.js 
{
$ node foo.js
/Users/dap/foo.js:3
});
 ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

I would suggest using a tool like javascriptlint to find the extra open brace.

Comment: Actually, thats the problem. Extra opening bracket, thanks alot!